# Error while trying to install gTTS (pip install gTTS)

Tags: python, pip, google-text-to-speech

I tried to install gTTS (Google text-to-speech) for a small project I've been doing and I am stuck with an error at installation of gTTS.

```
(bot) Vishnus-iMac:bin Code$ pip install gTTS
Collecting gTTS
Installing collected packages: gTTS
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 366, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 760, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 382, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/Users/Code/virtualenvironment/bot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 326, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: gTTS .dist-info directory not found
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is not related to `gTTS` but `pip`.
Try to exit virtualenvironment or update `pip` via `pip install pip -U`. And then try to install `gTTs` again.

Comment: Outside the virtualenv, it returns an EnvironmentError (Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/UNKNOWN-2.0.3.dist-info/RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.)

Comment: @Villyam It's weird. Have you tried `python3`? I've switched to `python3` for a long time and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I solve installation error of gTTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004965/how-can-i-solve-installation-error-of-gtts)

Following Steps can be done:

a) Upgrading the setuptools

```
pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```

b) Upgrading the pip

```
pip3 install pip --upgrade
```

c) Install gtts again, clearing pip cache

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir gTTS
```

Hope it helps.